# PHP - Obter soma do SQL através de Prepared Statment

Tags: php

Boas,

```
             $stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(product_qty) AS value FROM public_order_checklist WHERE order_code = '$order_code'");
             $stmt2->execute();
             $stmt2->bind_result($value);
             $stmt2->store_result();                
             $rowsx = $stmt2->fetch();
```

Gostaria de obter o resultado do total de todos os codigos "order_code",
Mas.. aparece erro:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\Superfacil_v1.4.6\inc\colaborator\delivery.php on line 374

Linha:  $rows = $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, percebi que você está usando PDO, certo? Nesse caso você poderia tentar dessa maneira:

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(product_qty) AS value FROM public_order_checklist WHERE order_code = :orderCode");
$stmt2->bindValue(":orderCode", $order_code);
$stmt2->execute();
$soma = $stmt2->fetchColumn();
```

Onde `$order_code` é o código que você quer usar na clausula `WHERE` e `$soma` contém o valor que você espera.